# How to write lexer rule that differentiates between -9 and - operator in arithmetic operation of 9 - 9?

Tags: antlr4

I am writing a simple expression parser using Antlr4 for calculator application. I have no idea of how to write a grammar that differentiate between digit -9 and arithmetic expression 9 - 9. Any kind of help is much appreciated

Here is my Grammar expression.g4:

```
grammar expression;

expression = expression ADDOPER expression
             | expression SUBOPER expression
             | NUMBER;

/* lexical rules */
ADDOPER     :'+';
SUBOPER     :'-';

NUMBER         : -?[1-9]+ [0-9]*('.'DIGIT+)? |'0'?('.'DIGIT+) |'0' ;
```

Problem with above grammar is that, it is matching `-9` as Number in the arithmetic expression `9 - 9` but which is supposed to be full arithmetic operation.

But `-9 + 9` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-9 is just an expression. So, simply do this:

```
expression
 : SUBOPER expression
 | expression ADDOPER expression
 | expression SUBOPER expression
 | NUMBER
 ;
```

and remove the `-` from your `NUMBER`:

```
NUMBER
 : [1-9] [0-9]* ( '.'DIGIT+ )? 
 | '0'? '.' DIGIT+ 
 | '0' 
 ;
```

Comment: hi @bhart, i think, i miss communicated, Problem is when i give `9 - 9` as input to the above grammar, it does not match `-` as operator instead it matched `-9` as Number. so my arithmetic expression has failed. My prefix tree should be like `operator(-), Number (9), Number(9)` but result was `Number(9), Number(-9)`.

Comment: Yes, I understood. My suggested changes should fix it. The grammar I suggest will correctly parse `9 - 9`, `9-9`, `-9 + 9`, ect

Comment: Good  to hear it, and you're welcome @SaravananRamupillai